# Sum of factorials

Tags: java, sum, factorial

So I need to output a sum of factorials like `1!+2!...+n!=sum` I found a way to get a single factorial but I don't know how to sum them together. This is my attempt at doing so:

```
 System.out.println("Ievadiet ciparu");
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      n = in.nextInt();
      if ( n < 0 )
         System.out.println("Ciparam jabut pozitivam.");
      else
      {
          while (x>2){
         for ( c = 1 ; c <= n ; c++ )
            fact = fact*c;
         sum=sum+fact;
         n=n-1;
        if (n==0) break;

      }
         System.out.println("Faktorialu summa "+sum);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than have a loop 1-n and calculate each factorial elsewhere, I would accumulate the sum *as you calculate* the factorials - ie have two local variables; one for factorial and one for the sum:

```
long factorial = 1, sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
     factorial *= i;
     sum += factorial;
}
```

When tested with `n = 5`, `sum` is `153`, which is correct: `1 + 2 + 6 + 24 + 120`

Your problem was that the sum was *outside* the loop - you just needed braces like here.

---

Also, your `while` loop condition `x < 2` will never change, so either the loop will never execute (if `x > 1`) or the loop will never terminate, because `x` is not changed within the loop.

Comment: He *doesn't*. Note that `sum=sum+fact` is outside of the factorial-calculating loop.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Oops, the missing brackets made me miss that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik 'Optional brackets' in Java should be equivalent to 'optional tabs' for Python.

Comment: @John Personally I'd hate it if they weren't optional. Code looses reading fluidity with them. Same for line breaks.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I'm with you - if there's only one line in the loop, I routinely omit the braces - you save a line of code (no solitary close brace taking up a whole line). As long as you use a code formater, you won't get into trouble with incorrectly indented code misleading the reader.

Comment: If the lines are short, I often include the subordinate clause on the same line. Typical idiom: `for (x : coll) if (condition on x) out.add(x)`. It's a sort of a "filter" idiom in a language without higher-order functions.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik for me, there's too much going on in your example to have it all on one line. However, I'm not *so* opposed to it that would edit such code into multiple lines if I saw it in production code - I would respect your decision to same-line it. I does look a bit too much like LISP though :)

Comment: You read me like an open book---yes, I got to like that style while being exposed to Clojure :)

Answer (score 0):

hmmm my search for finding a recursive(via recursive method calling) version of these code still getting nowhere

```
`public static long factorialSum(long n){
        long x = n;
        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++){
            x = (n-i)*(1+x);
        }
        return x;
    }`
```

if you just look at the problem more closely you'll see you can do it in linear time, the trick is in (n-1)! + n! = (n-1)!*(1 + n), to understand this more deeply i recommend add (n-2)! just to see how it grows.